# Firefox 23.0.1 changing my css, breaking website

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-color

I put up a test site for a client to look at for a proof of concept, and when cross checking browsers I noticed a white line that was not supposed to be there.

http://artistelisabeth.com/ (loads correctly in all other browsers except FF)

There is a ~10px line right above the footer when viewing in FF. Initially it looks like a simple fix, but its actually the bg of the body showing through.

I tried adding some simple solutions first padding-bottom on the parent element  or some margins on child elements. Nothing worked, only solution is a hack, adding a margin-top:-10px to the footer, or opposite style on the featured div.

Also. The only style in my css associated with the .featured div, is background: #ded1ae, this shows up correctly in all other browsers, but in FF it gets changed to background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(222, 209, 174);

I also noticed all my other bg colors were changed as well, and all hex colors changed to RGB.

This may be a simple solution, which I hope it is, and I am just having a brain lapse. But I am totally perplexed, and have never run across an issue like this.

Please help!

(I guess it should be noted that I am using the Skeleton boilerplate, but I have used this many times before with no issue, and I cant see how that would affect this.)

```
<div class="featured"> 
   <div class="container"> 
   </div> 
</div> 

.featured { background: #ded1ae; height: 100px; } 
.container { position: relative; width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }
```

Above is the css in all browsers except FF, in FF it shows up as

```
.featured { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DED1AE; height: 100px; }
```

Comment: -1 Your question should include code, not a link to a website, or it is useless to future visitors. See this meta topic: [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978/152515)

Comment: Without a visual example in a specific browser (ff) the code is useless.

Comment: A visual example can be provided in a screenshot. As long as you provide code which is a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/), people will be able to use it to reproduce the problem, and won't even need your visual example. Specifically, code which _doesn't_ let people reproduce the problem is useless. Not providing a good code example - one which reproduces the problem exactly - inside your question itself is [one of our reasons for closing a question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UXv1w.png). That is in addition to the sentiments expressed in the meta discussion I linked.

Comment: Your question still does not contain code "which reproduces the problem exactly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<hr class="remove-bottom">` in the `<footer>` causes the whitespace by having a `margin-top: 10px` and `clear: both`.

Setting `.remove-bottom { margin: 0; }` "fixes" it.

Not sure if it is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)/spec violation in Firefox or the other browsers.

Comment: Thank you for answering this, I found another workaround. But the answer is similar.

But another concern of mine, is why FF was changing the CSS?